# JMS container factory manual startup

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a Spring JMS application configured via annotations and I am trying to provide some information to the application BEFORE the JMS listeners start. After that,  I want to start manually the listeners.

With the following configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "queueContainerFactory")
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> queue(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqCf = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) cf;
        factory.setConnectionFactory(amqCf);
    ...
}
```

I saw the option: `factory.setAutoStartup(FALSE);`

With this the application context starts and the `@JmsListener` is not started but I do not know how to start the JMS container factory manually.

```
@JmsListener(containerFactory="queueContainerFactory", destination = "${destination}")
    public void jmsListener(String message) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to autowire `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` and obtain the particular `MessageListenerContainer` by its `id`. Where that `id` you can configure on the `@JmsListener`:

```
/**
 * The unique identifier of the container managing this endpoint.
 * <p>If none is specified, an auto-generated one is provided.
 * @see org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry#getListenerContainer(String)
 */
String id() default "";
```

That might look like:

```
@JmsListener(id ="myContainer", 
           containerFactory="queueContainerFactory", 
           destination = "${destination}")
    public void jmsListener(String message) {
...
}

...

@Autowired
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry jmsListenerEndpointRegistry;

...

this.jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();
```

Comment: Or you can `start()` the registry and it will start all the registered containers.